# How to run call back functions while playing audio in python?

Tags: python, audio, callback, signal-processing

Just a little background to what I am trying to achieve. I am using [Audioowl](https://github.com/dodiku/AudioOwl) python library for beat detection and music analyses. After analyzing a music file, the audioowl `analyse_samples()` function gives information on notes, beats and time when a beat happens in the audio. I want to play the file and execute a call back function every time audio timestamp matches the beat time stamp. Is there any python library which supports this?